# At physiological pH, why isn't the amide of glutamine protonated?

Tags: amino-acids, protons

If the amide in the R group of glutamine has a pKa of 15, then pKa is certainly greater than physiological pH. We'd expect it to be pronated, then, but basically all diagrams of glutamine at physiological pH show it just as...an amine with NH2 and C=O.

Why wouldn't the amide be protonated? If so, where would the protonation site be — would it be an NH3⁺ as if it were an amine?

Comment: You think into the wrong direction. What is the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ value of the amide? Or the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of the corresponding acid? Also, are you aware that the lone pair on the nitrogen is in conjugation with the carbonyl and what this means for its accessibility for protonation?

Comment: pKa 15 belongs to amide as an acid , you want to protonate it as a base. That is a different acid/base pair.

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/45249/what-test-can-be-used-to-differ-amide-and-amine/46286?r=SearchResults&s=3|19.0845#46286

Comment: because it is completely non-basic

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There are two equilibria, one between the deprotonated amide (one hydrogen, negative charge) and the amide (two hydrogens, neutral), and the other between the amide (two hydrogens, neutral) and the protonated amide (three hydrogens, positive charge). The major species is the one in the middle.

If you try hard to protonate an amide in aqueous solution, the proton might attach to the oxygen instead of the nitrogen, see e.g. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo962063z.

A $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 15 means that the amide is a very weak acid and will not lose its proton even at very basic pH, i.e. the species on the left will not form in aqueous solution. To give an example using other acids and bases: acetic acid, with a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 3.75, will be deprotonated at pH 7. One the other hand, the ammonium ion, with a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of about 9, will be protonated at pH 7. So if the pH is lower than the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$, the major species is the protonated one (of the equilibrium you are looking at). If the pH is higher than the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$, the major species is the deprotonated one.

> If the amide in the R group of glutamine has a pKa of 15, then pKa is certainly greater than physiological pH. We'd expect it to be pronated, then, but basically all diagrams of glutamine at physiological pH show it just as...an amine with NH2 and C=O.

It is protonated. If it acted as an acid, it would lose one of its two protons, and aquire a negative charge.

> Why wouldn't the amide be protonated? If so, where would the protonation site be — would it be an NH3⁺ as if it were an amine?

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ for $\ce{R-CO-NH3+}$ is on the order of -0.5, so it would not be the major species at neutral pH (or in aqueous solution of any pH, for that matter). Instead, it would act as an acid, yielding the amide. As mentioned above, if an amide does get protonated, it might either become O-protonated or N-protonated, depending on the specific amide and the conditions.